# How to diagnose dual channel memory / motherboard?

Tags: linux, memory, motherboard

I have `ASUS P7P55-M` with 12GiB of memory, but it sees only half of it:

```
dims@sagittarius-a:~$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
MemTotal:        6102272 kB
```

Simultaneously, it is visible from OS service commands, that all memory exist:

```
dims@sagittarius-a:~$ sudo lshw -short -C memory
H/W path        Device     Class       Description
==================================================
/0/0                       memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4/5                     memory      256KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                     memory      1MiB L2 cache
/0/4/7                     memory      8MiB L3 cache
/0/30                      memory      12GiB System Memory
/0/30/0                    memory      2GiB DIMM DDR Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/30/1                    memory      4GiB DIMM DDR Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/30/2                    memory      4GiB DIMM DDR Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/30/3                    memory      2GiB DIMM DDR Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
```

How to diagnose what is malfunctionning? Motherboard "channel", or memory card or what?

Comment: what is your OS and is it 64 bit ? if its windows then is it professional or what ? please add task manager memory tab pic too thnaks

Comment: OS is Ubuntu x64. The DIMMs are probably mixing slots, but how to see that?

Comment: it should support it but i'm not the linux guy sorry bro